# Django Redirect vs Revese error

Tags: python, django, django-views

Looking at the documentation it seems that redirect is a shortcut for creating an HTTP request with a reverse inside. I have the following working code:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post-detail', args=(self.kwargs['pk'],)))
```

I would expect the same thing to work as a redirect, with the parameters passed to reverse:

```
return redirect('post-detail', args=(self.kwargs['pk'],))
```

Although, when using the redirect, I get exception for not matching the URL. What am I missing?

```
url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$', views.PostDetailView.as_view(), name="post-detail"),
```

The error when using redirect:

> Reverse for 'post-detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments
>   '{'args': (u'5905064635924480',)}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
>   ['post/(?P[\d]+)/$']

Answer (score 1):

the signature of `redirect` is different from `reverse`, as you can see from the error, which shows it is using `*args, **kwargs` rather than taking keyword arguments called `args` and `kwargs`

(see also the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)

so you want:

```
return redirect('post-detail', self.kwargs['pk'])
```

or

```
return redirect('post-detail', pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
```